# avoiding losing precision with nawk option

Tags: awk

I have a data file consists of rows with numeric data. The example of numeric data is 4053.45677771. When I perform arithmetic operation with nawk like;

```
 nawk -F, '{print $1*1000}' data > data_2
```

numeric values in data_2 file looks with exponential and precision is lost like; `4.05346e+06` How can I multiply with 1000 without exponential usage and precision lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf` for finer control over the output:

```
$ echo 4053.45677771 | nawk '{printf "%f\n",$1*1000}'
4053456.777710
```

So, for your example:

```
nawk -F, '{printf "%f\n",$1*1000}' data > data_2
```

You can also stick to `print` if you set the `OFMT` variable (POSIX.1-2008 supports it):

```
$ echo 4053.45677771 | nawk -vOFMT='%f' '{print $1*1000}'  
4053456.777710
```